# Security problem: catalog/product_list Error message in system.log

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, whitelist

This morning I got the error `2016-02-12T12:51:12+00:00 DEBUG (7): Security problem: catalog/product_list has not been whitelisted.` in the `system.log` file.

I don't want to whitelist it before knowing what it is!

But i can't find any file or block called **product_list**.  How would one go about finding any file, block or CMS page containing "product_list"?

Comment: There are one issue already created and solved. Follow this [Security Problem Magento Blocks](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101562/security-problem-catalog-product-list-error-message-in-system-log)

Answer (score 4):

Magento backend interface. Simply navigate to

```
System -> Permissions -> Blocks
```

and Add new  block type catalog/product_list and set Allowed to Yes

Comment: perfect!!! saved my time +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

Some text that is processed by the template filter is trying to use the block `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List`. This is normally most likely a CMS Static Block, CMS Page or CMS Widget.

Check your Apache / nginx logs for the same time and see which URL was requested at the time the error was logged, this should give you a good idea of where it can be located in the DB.

Alternatively, think about somewhere that used to display a list of products on your website (other than a category page or search result) and go and look if the list is still present. It could be something like a Mega Menu, or a widget on the homepage that show's latest products.